# Android Studio APK Build zipalign issue and Zipalign.exe flashes screen

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-tools

[image: Android Studio zipalign.exe error]

Whenever I try to APK Build my application, I'm greeted with this error. I tried to resolve this issue by already updating my SDK Manager and copying the *zip-align.exe* tool from **~\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W** to **~\sdk\tools** and that did not resolve the issue either. Also I've tried to run the *zip-align.exe* file through administrator and a terminal screen just flashes the screen. I don't have much Gradle experience, but I did enter zipAlign true into my Gradle. This also failed.

```
buildTypes {

 release {
    runProguard false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    zipAlign true
}
```

After experimenting all of the above, I did undo them. I don't know how else to zip-align my APK. Any help would be nice, thanks.

Comment: "Also I've tried to run the zip-align.exe file through administrator and a terminal screen just flashes the screen" -- you need to run it via command prompt. Also, Android 4.4W is for Android Wear devices, so unless you're making an app for a smartwatch, you probably just want Android 4.4, but that's probably not the cause of this issue.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to run the zipalign.exe manually. Except now I can't find the zipaplign output apk file. I would assume that the output file would be in the same folder as the input apk file. I'll take note about 4.4w.

Comment: You could try specifying the outfile if you didn't, although I'd think that's a required parameter: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html - doesn't say much about where it outputs to, though.

Comment: It should be saved in the same directory by default. zipalign -f -v 4 AppFile.apk AppFile2.apk